# Is there a way to use 'localhost' with mysqli_connect and force TCP connection?

Tags: php, mysqli

I know this is a bit unusual question, but I am looking for a way to execute code like this:

```php
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', null, 'mydb');
```

And instead of going to UNIX socket connection I would like it to use TCP. I know this can be done by changing localhost to 127.0.0.1 but is there a way to use localhost as host and get the same result? Through some kind of configuration etc?

To clarify further I am asking - Is there a way to configure PHP, OS or whatever to change how connection to mysql database is made through mysqli_connect in such way that when 'localhost' is used as host php interprets it as TCP connection and not as UNIX socket connection?

Comment: When using `localhost` the mysql driver will attempt to use the local Unix socket, regardless of if it actually exists or not. Using `127.0.0.1` will use TCP. If you can't change the hostname used by the software, then you'll need to make mysql's Unix socket work. The only other way around this would be compiling a custom mysql driver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is actually a way to solve this problem (on Linux). I discovered tool called [socat](https://linux.die.net/man/1/socat) that is capable of proxying the unix socket to TCP and vice versa.

What I did was following:

1. Configured php.ini to contain this setting

   ```
   mysqli.default_socket = "/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock"
   ```
2. Created directory `/run/mysqld`
3. Initiated socat process

   ```
   socat UNIX-LISTEN:/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock,fork,reuseaddr,unlink-early,user=root,group=root,mode=777 TCP:127.0.0.1:3306 &
   ```
4. And then it all started working

Comment: A very clever solution.

Answer (score 1):

The manual says:

> The TCP/IP protocol is used if a host name and port number are
> provided together e.g. localhost:3308.

See: https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php

Comment: I was trying to simplify my problem by giving this dummy code example but it is not as simple as that. I am using an existing piece of software, that I can not modify, which in turn calls another piece of software that again I can not modify that assumes connection host as localhost and port as null that end's up going to socket connection.

Comment: @DarkoMiletic - Are you asking us how you can change the connection without changing any code or connection config? Please edit your question and include all specs/restrictions.

Comment: @DarkoMiletic: OK, got it. No changes to any scripts. Can you modify the MySQL configuration? I don't know if you can do it there, but if you cannot modify it then there's no point even trying it.

Comment: I can change both php and mysql configuration

Comment: I thought about this and I don't think changing anything on the MySQL side could work because PHP initiates the connection. Refusing a pipe connection on the MySQL side would just mean that there's no connection. I also don't see any [configuration setting](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.configuration.php) that would do the trick. This seems impossible?